# Finding average distance from polygon to multiple points

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, proximity

I am trying to find the average distance from a polygon to multiple points on a map. Specifically from a parcel to "downtown hubs". I have used the "Near" tool to generate a table showing the distance from each parcel to each point. Now I want to average the distances for each point. Then join the result for each FID back to another feature class in a new field.

My current table is below

[image]

I want this to become something like:

INPUT_FID | DISTANCE

1  |   xxxxx

2 | xxxxx

3 | xxxxx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Summary Statistics](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/summary-statistics.htm) for this.

Use **INPUT_FID** as your **case** field and **DISTANCE** as your **statistics** field. Use **MEAN** for your statistic type.